# How to sort the order of a foreach if array_reverse isn't doing the job?

Tags: php

Here is a `var_dump` of a multidimensional array.

```
array (size=2)
  'ad795f9b369fc967db8fe0611ecc3cb3' => 
    array (size=6)
      'rowid' => string 'ad795f9b369fc967db8fe0611ecc3cb3' (length=32)
      'id' => string '101_89765' (length=9)
      'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
      'price' => string '19.00' (length=5)
      'name' => string 'Product 2' (length=13)
      'subtotal' => float 19

  '19c452c64c3f308323dee72a8a4a4f62' => 
    array (size=6)
      'rowid' => string '19c452c64c3f308323dee72a8a4a4f62' (length=32)
      'id' => string '114_54828' (length=9)
      'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
      'price' => string '452.25' (length=6)
      'name' => string 'Product 1' (length=5)
      'subtotal' => float 452.25
```

I need to flip the order so that it will display in the reverse `product 1` before `product 2`.  I tried using `array_reverse` before the `foreach` but it has no effect.

What else can I do? Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: For whoever may need help in the future ... I solved this problem by assigning `array_reverse` within the `foreach` and set a `,true` param to preserve_keys -- code: `foreach (array_reverse($array, true) as $each)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_reverse` does not accept it's parameter by reference (as sort functions), instead it just *returns the reversed array*.

So you should use `$array = array_reverse($array);`

Comment: Yeah I did it inline as follows: `foreach (array_reverse($array, true) as $each) `